# ng-class dynamic doesn't change when resize window

Tags: angularjs, ternary-operator, ng-class

I tried the ng-class directive with a ternary and it works very well when the page load. My reference is the widthWindow.xs variable, it is "true" when the window size is a mobile, but there is a resize put it to "false" but the class does not change, the ng-class not dynamically changes. Why?

in the controller:

```
$scope.myResize = funcion(){
   var number = $window.innerWidth;
   if (number > 767) {
      $scope.widthWindow.xs = false;
   }else{
      $scope.widthWindow.xs = true;
   }
};
```

in the html:

```
<p ng-class="widthWindow.xs ? 'borderVoteNewsTop' : 'borderVoteNewsLeft'">Don't change when there is a resize</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 'resize' event comes form outside the Angular framework, you need to integrate its actions with the AngularJS digest cycle. Use `$apply`.

```
$scope.myResize = function(){
   var number = $window.innerWidth;
   if (number > 767) {
      $scope.$apply("widthWindow.xs = false");
   }else{
      $scope.$apply("widthWindow.xs = true");
   }
};
```

After the `$apply` executes the Angular expression, it will automatically invoke a digest cycle and the watcher in the `ng-class` directive will see the change and update the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the `ngClass` directive is not correct.

Use it as following:

```
<p 
  ng-class="{'borderVoteNewsTop': widthWindow.xs, 'borderVoteNewsLeft': !widthWindow.xs}"
>
  Change when there is a resize
</p>
```

> Check out the directive documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: This is another possibility but with $scope.$apply() it work perfect now. Thanks